# вывод на принтер в консольном приложении

Tags: c++, c

При печати в консоли выводит сообщение "'путь' в настоящее время печается"

```
     case 5:
            if( ( Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "rb" ) ) == NULL )
            {
                puts( "\n Open ERROR! Press any key!" );
                getch();

                continue;
            }
            printf( "\n\tGroup number" );
            printf( "\n\n\t" );
            scanf("%d", &n_gr_print);
            printf( "\n\tMark" );
            printf( "\n\n\t" );
            scanf("%d", &s_b_print);

            Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "rb" );
            D_f = fileno( Fz );
            len = filelength( D_f );
            kol = len / size;
            mas_Z = new TZap[kol];

            for( i = 0; i < kol; i++ )
            {
                fread( ( mas_Z + i ), size, 1, Fz );
            }

            fclose( Fz );
                    for( int i = 0; i < kol; i++ )
                            if(mas_Z[i].n_gr == n_gr_print && mas_Z[i].s_b > s_b_print)
                            {
                                    printf("\n\t%s;", mas_Z[i].FIO );
                                    k_print++;

                                    fprintf( Ft, "\n F.I.O. = %s,\n Year of birth = %d,\n Group number = %d,\n Physics = %d,\n Mathematics = %d,\n Computer science = %d,\n Chemistry = %d,\n Mark = %1f\n\n\t", mas_Z[i].FIO, mas_Z[i].god_r, mas_Z[i].n_gr, mas_Z[i].ocen_fiz, mas_Z[i].ocen_mat, mas_Z[i].ocen_inf, mas_Z[i].ocen_him, mas_Z[i].s_b );
                            }
                            printf("\n");
                            if(k_print == 0)
                                    printf("\n\tNo information");
                            else {
                                    fclose( Ft );
                                    system("print rezult.txt");
                                    Ft = fopen( File_Rez, "a" );
                            }
            delete []mas_Z;

            break;
```

Comment: Ладно, пусть выводит. А проблема-то в чем? Что отладчик говорит?

Comment: @IKSUY Всё работает, у меня на принтер не идет печать и в консоли выводит то сообщение. system("print rezult.txt"); - это же вывод на печать?

Comment: А вы запустите `print rezult.txt` вручную, и посмотрите, что получается. Может, вы не в том каталоге находитесь, кто ж знает.

Comment: @VladD через cmd так не удается инициализировать устройство PRN. Путь верный

Comment: @Евгений: Эээ, какое «устройство PRN»? У нас же не 1990 год. Утилита `print` ничего общего с допотопным устройством PRN не имеет (и слава богу).

Comment: @Евгений: А если вам утилита `print` пишет, что документ в настоящее время уже печатается, то может быть, так оно и есть? Загляните в свойства принтера, небось бумага закончилась.

Comment: @vladD Принтер работает, с ОС всё печатает, единственное, принтер сетевой, но думаю это не имеет значения. Про prn ничего не знаю, при выполнении из файла пишет уже печатается, а из cmd ошибка prn.

Comment: @VladD Хотя уже пишет что уже печатается

Comment: @VLADD На компьютере на котором установлен принтер тоже пишет что уже печатает.  Если из ОС печатать то всё ок.

Comment: @Евгений: Ну вот. Может быть, стоит не открывать файл заново, пока не будет окончена печать?

Comment: @vladD Дело в том что такое же пишет и при печати другого файла из командной строки, и на принтере который подключен напрямую к принтеру и на сетевом.

Comment: **print** - это вообще, что за команда ? Вы в какой ОС работаете? Если в Linux. то для печати файла из командной строки надо использовать команду вида "lpr -P <Имя принтера в системе> <Имя распечатываемого файла>

Comment: @sergey windows

Comment: @Евгений гляньте [тут] (http://superuser.com/questions/477895/printing-from-windows-7-command-line)